# How to print line from thread without messing with current input line in main thread

Tags: c++, windows, console

Let say that I have a server loop that will print something out
how do I keep that input line at the last line when server thread doing print

```
int main() {
  std::thread th(server_thread);

  th.detach();

  while (!th.joinable()) {
    std::string message;
    printf("Input: ");
    std::getline(std::cin, message);
    printf("Message: %s\n", message.c_str());
  }

  th.join();
}
```

Comment: I recommend reading this documentation on [`std::thread::detach`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/detach).

Comment: If you have two threads writing to the same stream you are doomed to a rough time. C and C++ IO is too simple by design to handle what you want to do. I recommend having one thread be responsible for all console IO and the other threads tell it what to write via a message queue.

Comment: A more intelligent console library [like the curses family](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curses_(programming_library)) might also be helpful to you. I still recommend not interacting with it from more than one thread.

Comment: Why are you mixing C-style I/O and C++-style I/O? Pick one or the other and stick with it.